# Yesod POST disabling CSRF

Tags: haskell, yesod

I did disable session by using

```
makeSessionBackend _ = return Nothing
```

As stated in Yesod book, but I am still getting CSRF problems while testing my JSON API. How can I disable this feature properly?

I am getting this message when I make the request with `curl`

```
The `defaultCsrfMiddleware` Middleware added in Foundation.hs adds a CSRF token the request cookies
```

I am not using `defaultCsrfMiddleware`

Comment: do you set it at all? Is there something like `yesodMiddleware = defaultYesodMiddleware`?

Comment: @Carsten Yes, there is a `yesodMiddleware = defaultYesodMiddlewere`

Comment: well this is strange - can you rgrep (find in file) your project for `Crsf` and see if maybe it's still enabled somewhere?

Comment: @Carsten There is neither `Csrf` nor `Crsf` in my files.

Comment: you don't use any of these right? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.20.2/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#g:28 - can you post the handler and maybe the complete error?

Comment: AFAIK this: `csrfErrorMessage = "A valid CSRF token wasn't present in HTTP headers or POST parameters. Because the request could have been forged, it's been rejected altogether. Check the Yesod.Core.Handler docs of the yesod-core package for details on CSRF protection."` is the error message that should happen

Comment: I don't use these functions, and the message you posted is exactly what I receive, I am using the scaffolding, yesod-mysql

Comment: if you really don't use it and have disabled the middleware then you should probably open an [issue here](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod)

Comment: Today I tested the very same thing again, without changing anything, and it worked! Why? I remember I did rebuild and relaunched `stack`, why didn't it work? Well... Thank you for trying to help me so far.